# Вызов Navigation Drawer Menu из toolbar в Android ниже 5 версии (Navigation Drawer Menu от Mike Penz)

Tags: java, android, android-navigation-drawer

Я использую Navigation Drawer Menu от [Mike Penz](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) с тулбаром.

Код создания тулбара:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.mipmap.ic_action_menu);
```

В Android версии 5 и выше все замечательно работает, при нажатии на иконку которую я задал с помощью setNavigationIcon меню открывается, но в Android версий ниже 5ой создается ощущение, что тулбар просто не кликабелен, я пытался повешать на него setNavigationOnClickListener и даже просто setOnClickListener, но он на это никак не реагирует.

Каким образом можно заставить выдвигаться Navigation Drawer Menu с помощью иконки навигации в тулбаре в Android ниже 5 версии?

Comment: Не хватает ссылки на используемую либу. Не хватает кода коий обрабатывает нажатие нужное. Обычно это в `onOptionItemsSelected`.

Comment: Ссылку на используемую библиотеку добавил, а какой-то специальный код который обрабатывает нужное нажатие я не писал... при этом на пятом андройде и выше иконка гамбургера нормально работает, так же я пытался искользовать вот эту строчку: `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` в этом случае стрелка назад есть, но ситуация такая же, на андройде ниже 5ой версии не работает.

Comment: Может быть нажатие этой кнопки на андройде версии ниже чем 5 надо обрабатывать как то по другому? Если да, не могли бы вы привести пример)

Comment: Вы используете методы `withActivity()`,`withTollbar()` при создании бокового меню? Там в исходниках, есть сэмпл - внимательно его изучите. Раньше я пользовался данной библиотекоц и все работало и на версиях ниже 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте помимо ручного отображения иконки обработать нажатие на неё

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(id == android.R.id.home)
    {
        //тут открывать дровер
        return true;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за пример, попробую. Кстати на андройде выше 5го кнопка работает когда в toolbar в activity_main добавлен атрибут `android:elevation="4dp"`

Comment: @Phoenix888, к вопросу это, конечно, не относится, но я всё же не советую пользовать библиотеки для того, что можно стандартными средствами сделать. По крайней мере в данном случае
)

Comment: Проблема была очень банальна, во всем виновата моя неопытность)) на самом деле просто был не там размещен атрибут `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` из за этого toolbar был перекрыт другим лэйаутом, и из за этого ничего не нажималось на самом тулбаре. На андройде выше 5го работало как я уже сказал из за атрибута `android:elevation="4dp"` - это для меня пока не очень понятно.